# SQL and IBM I systems

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have an SQL solution that retrieves similar **quotenumber**# from **contractnumber#** across 2 tables (QUOTES and CLIENTS) respectively.  This works fine in any SQL Fiddle on the internet. See all the SQL below to create the solution ( *I have added the create and insert tables statements just for easy of making the SELECT statement work*):

```
CREATE TABLE QUOTES
(`quotenumber` varchar(10));

INSERT INTO QUOTES
(`quotenumber`)
VALUES
('10006'),
('10007'),
('10008'),
('10009');

CREATE TABLE CLIENTS
(`contractnumber` varchar(21));

INSERT INTO CLIENTS
(`contractnumber`)
 VALUES
('PRXQTE-10006'),
('PRXQTE-10007'),
('FRR-13'),
('JK1222222'),
('X'),
('');
```

**This is the SELECT statement:**

```
SELECT H.quotenumber
FROM QUOTES as H
INNER JOIN CLIENTS as P 
ON P.contractnumber LIKE CONCAT('%', H.quotenumber, '%');
```

However this SELECT statement does not work when I run this SQL in an IBM I environment.  For example when I try to run the SELECT statement below in **IBM I Access Client Solution's** sql editor I get this error:

> **SQL State: 42605 Vendor Code: -170 Message:** [SQL0170] Number of
> arguments for function CONCAT not valid. Cause . . . . . :   A
> function has been specified with an incorrect number of arguments. If
> this function is meant to be a user-defined function reference, a
> function with this signature was not found using the current path.
> Recovery  . . . :   Correct the number of arguments specified for the
> function.  Refer to the DB2 for IBM i SQL Reference topic collection
> in the Database category in the IBM i Information Center for
> information on functions. If this is a user-defined function, correct
> the path or the function signature. Try the request again.

Does anyone know the DB2 adaptation of this SELECT Statement or what alternative will work with IBM i ?

Comment: You can use https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1 as a DB2 test bed.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. You know i was searching all over for a db2 fiddle. Thanks

Comment: . . My only caution is that there seems to be almost as many variants of DB2 as of Sybase.  So it should be fine for the basics (such as your question) but might differ from your actual database.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, according to the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000781.html?pos=2) sadly `concat()` in DB2 can only take (exactly) two arguments:

> The CONCAT function combines two arguments to form a string expression.

You can work around that by nesting `concat()` calls like:

```
... concat(concat('%', h.quotenumber), '%') ...
```

That isn't beautiful but should work in DB2 and also in DBMS where `concat()` accepts an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: In Db2 CONCAT is also an operator, `'%' concat h.quotenumber concat '%'`  Also the Db2 for IBM i reference is here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=expressions-concatenation-operator

Comment: You can also use double pipes to concatenate strings as well: `'%' || h.quotenumber || '%'`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution that is a workaround and runs in DB2 (I added a second column to prove it retrieves the correct the correct corresponding quote#s):

```
SELECT H.quotenumber, P.contractnumber FROM QUOTES as H  
             INNER JOIN CLIENTS as P ON H.quotenumber = SUBSTRING( P.contractnumber, 8, 5 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sql
SELECT H.quotenumber
  FROM QUOTES as H
  JOIN CLIENTS as P 
    ON P.contractnumber LIKE '%' || H.quotenumber, || '%';
```

but you shouldnt because it literally fucks up every index in your db. See [this](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out still